# Rails string as a foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-migration

I have a relation between `User` and `Course` (typical enrollment data). A `User` `has_many` `Course` and vice-versa (typical `JOIN` table scenario).

I am attempting to migrate my previous `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between these two models to a `has_many :through` relationship. My files currently look like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
end
```

and

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

and the table name that joins the two models is `courses_users`.

I now need to migrate this relationship to the `has_many :through` association, and also make the column type of `user_id` a `string`, as I want to use the `g_number` (string) attribute of `User` as the foreign key. **Note**: I don't care about the performance difference between `int` and `varchar/string`.

**The short and simple problem is that I need `users.g_number` to reference `enrollments.user_id` as a foreign key, and both are strings.**

My attempt at a migration and model rework is this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :enrollment
    has_many :courses, :through => :enrollment
end
```

and

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :enrollment
    has_many :users, :through => :enrollment
end
```

lastly

```
class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :course
    belongs_to :user
end
```

then the migration

```
class ChangeUserIdJoin < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
        rename_table :courses_users, :enrollments
    end

    def self.down
        rename_table :enrollments, :courses_users
    end
end
```

**Everything works fine here**. I can do queries like `User.courses` and `Course.users`. But now I want to change the type of the `user_id` column in the join table to a `string` so that I can store the `g_number` (string attribute on `User`) and join on *that* instead of the serial `id` column of `User`.

When I attempt to change the `user_id` column type to `string` in the migration:

```
class ChangeUserIdJoin < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
        change_column :courses_users, :user_id, :string
        rename_table :courses_users, :enrollments
    end

    def self.down
        rename_table :enrollments, :courses_users
        change_column :courses_users, :user_id, :integer
    end
end
```

the queries `Course.users` and `User.courses` start failing (below from Rails console). `User.courses` returns an empty array (whereas before there are multiple `Course` objects), and `Course.users` throws an exception because of mismatched column types (which obviously makes sense):

```
u = User.take
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, username: "director", g_number: "g00000000", password_digest: "$2a$10$dvcOd3rHfbcR1Rn/D6VhsOokj4XiIkQbHxXLYjy5s4f...", created_at: "2016-01-06 01:36:00", updated_at: "2016-01-06 01:36:00", first_name: "Director", last_name: "", role: 0, registered: true> 
2.1.5 :002 > u.courses
  Course Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "courses".* FROM "courses" INNER JOIN "enrollments  ON "courses"."id" = "enrollments"."course_id" WHERE "enrollments"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []> 
2.1.5 :003 > c = Course.take
  Course Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "courses".* FROM "courses"  LIMIT 1
 => #<Course id: 12754, year: 2015, semester: 0, department: 7, course: 101, section: 1, name: "SPA 101 01 - Elementary Spanish I"> 
2.1.5 :004 > c.users
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = character varying
LINE 1: ... "users" INNER JOIN "enrollments" ON "users"."id" = "enrollm...
```

I need to be able to join on `enrollments.user_id = users.g_number`. What do I need to do in order to change the `user_id` column to a `string` type in the `Enrollment` model/table, and still be able to do Active Record queries like `User.courses` and `Course.users`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try by specifying the foreign and primary keys in enrollments model, like this

```
belongs_to :user foreign_key: :user_id, primary_key: :g_number
```

Comment: You are a **lifesaver**. I have been working on this for about 6 hours trying to figure out the correct relationship between them! In order to have the reverse query working (`Course.users`) I also needed to add `has_many :enrollment, foreign_key: :user_id, primary_key: :g_number` in the `User` model.